Why does the processing speed differ depending on the location of the @Transactional annotation in Spring?
package com.example.test;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@Transactional
public class TestController {
    private final StudentService studentService;

    @PostMapping("/test1")
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 500000; i++) {
            studentService.studentSave("학생_" + i);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("실행 시간: " + (end - start) + "ms");
    }

    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public void test2() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Task task1 = new Task(1, 100000);
        Task task2 = new Task(100001, 200000);
        Task task3 = new Task(200001, 300000);
        Task task4 = new Task(300001, 400000);
        Task task5 = new Task(400001, 500000);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task1, "thread1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task2, "thread2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(task3, "thread3");
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(task4, "thread4");
        Thread thread5 = new Thread(task5, "thread5");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        thread5.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
            thread3.join();
            thread4.join();
            thread5.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("실행 시간: " + (end - start) + "ms");
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {

        private final int start;
        private final int end;

        public Task(int start, int end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public void studentSave() {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + i);
                studentService.studentSave("학생_" + i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            studentSave();
        }
    }

}

package com.example.test;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentJpaRepository studentJpaRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void studentSave(String studentName) {
        studentJpaRepository.save(new Student(studentName));
    }

    public void studentAll() {
        studentJpaRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

I have the following controller and service code.
When the @Transactional annotation is declared at the class level, there is no significant speed difference when calling test1 and test2.
However, when the @Transactional annotation is declared at the method level, the speed of test1 becomes very slow, while test2 remains fast.
Why is this happening?
Also, when using a method without @Transactional and performing a simple print (not JPA save), the speed is fast. Therefore, it seems that the slowness is caused by the impact of @Transactional. What could be the reason for this in AOP, or where and why does the slowness occur?
test2 is still fast.
I set up H2 and conducted the test locally. As described above, I tested with the @Transactional annotation at different locations, and even when I created only Task1 and set the loop range to 100,000, I still confirmed that the logic inside the loop was slow.

On the class there is 1 transaction, on the method there are 500000 individual small transactions. Now if the tx overhead is 2 ms... This will result in 500000 * 2ms overhead for the individual calls on overhead (about 20 seconds). Note this is just an example as the numbers for the overhead are made up!.

Thank you for your feedback. In that case, with @Transactional declared in studentSave, why is it, based on a 2ms overhead per task, that for 100,000 tasks, the total time should be 200,000 ms? Even when the range of the for loop in test1 is set to 100,000, like task1, instead of 500,000, test2 is still faster, and test1 remains slow. What could be the reason for this?

It is not the total time it is the overhead! Transactions are thread bound so the @Transactional with threads doesn't do anything, it will execute 5 concurrent threads so it will execute in roughly 20% of the time  of test1 without a tx.
